# Strange FileNotFoundException occuring on production server in console application

Tags: .net, active-directory

Hi I have an application that works fine in my dev enviroment, but throws weird errors in the production enviroment, I checked the version of .net on my dev machine aswell as the production server , they both run 3.5.30729.01.

The exception I get is a System.IO.FileNotFoundException.

StackTrace:

```
at System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(String fileName)
at System.Configuration.ClientConfigPaths.SetNamesAndVersion(String applicationFilename, Assembly exeAssembly, Boolean isHttp)
at System.Configuration.ClientConfigPaths..ctor(String exePath, Boolean includeUserConfig)
at System.Configuration.ClientConfigPaths.GetPaths(String exePath, Boolean includeUserConfig)
at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationHost.get_ConfigPaths()
at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationHost.RequireCompleteInit(IInternalConfigRecord record)
at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.GetSectionRecursive(String configKey, Boolean getLkg, Boolean checkPermission, Boolean getRuntimeObject, Boolean requestIsHere, Object& result, Object& resultRuntimeObject)
at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.GetSection(String configKey)
at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem.System.Configuration.Internal.IInternalConfigSystem.GetSection(String sectionName)
at System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.GetSection(String sectionName)
at System.Configuration.PrivilegedConfigurationManager.GetSection(String sectionName)
at System.DirectoryServices.SearchResultCollection.ResultsEnumerator..ctor(SearchResultCollection results, String parentUserName, String parentPassword, AuthenticationTypes parentAuthenticationType)
at System.DirectoryServices.SearchResultCollection.GetEnumerator()
at System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher.FindOne()
```

Yesterday the error just went away, and today the error is occuring again. I tried using reflector on System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher.FindOne() following the calls and it appears to have something to do with config files or user config files as you can see from the stacktrace

any ideas as to what config file it is trying to find and why it can't find them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) (or enhance you logging) to identify which file is not being found.

Comment: I am not really sure how i'm supposed to enhance my logging when the error occurs in a system method I have no control over

Comment: @thmsn: that is not completely clear from the question. But the primary suggestion is to determine what is happening at the file system level that's failing.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with sysinternal "FileMon".

It's an application that catches every IO attempt, succesful or not. With pacience, you will see the name of the file not found.

Comment: Process Monitor will always be filemon to me :)

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered this problem. In my case, when I pulled my release application from my build server and ran it on my development machine, I got the FileNotFoundException from a chain of calls stemming from FindOne. I was running this release version from my Desktop, which the impersonated account doesn't have full access too. I moved the release folder to the C drive and it ran fine.
In my case this code is executed for a login dialog that allows multiple login attempts. It fails the first time for the above reason, but succeeds the next time, which seems odd. I can only assume FindOne ultimately follows a different path the second time but I haven't truly found the exact problem at this point.  The access problem makes sense in my case, so I just won't run from there.
Maybe this is more of a clue to others than a solution.